# Run function AFTER route fully rendered in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

### Background:

I'm building an SSR website using Nuxt. I want to run a script to [fix some typography issues](https://github.com/andybelldesign/typemate) (orphaned text in headers). I can't do this UNTIL AFTER the DOM is rendered. How can I implement this function once so it runs after each page's DOM is rendered? It can be either in the Router or in a Nuxt Layout, or elsewhere.

### What I've tried:

1. In my `layout.vue`, `Mounted()` only runs on the first load (as expected) and adding `$nextTick` doesn't seem to affect that. This is even true for generated static pages served from a real webserver.
2. In my `layout.vue`, using Vue's `Updated()` never seems to fire. I assume this means Nuxt is getting in the way.
3. Using `app.router.afterEach()` the function runs on each route change (including first load), but way before the DOM is rendered making it worthless.
4. If I add `Vue.nextTick()` into the `.afterEach()` the function runs on the current page JUST BEFORE the route changes (you can see it flash) but DOES NOT run before that.

### What works but seems dumb:

Putting the function in the `Mounted()` block on each page.

```
mounted: function(){
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    const tm = new TypeMate(undefined, { selector: 'h2, h3, p, li' });
    tm.apply();
     
    })
  },
```

But this seems like a bad idea especially as we add pages. What am I missing? Is there a smart way to do this? Nuxt's documentation is next to useless for some of this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) with mounted function. Lifecycle hooks from mixin will be merged with your lifecycle events and each will be run.

Comment: Hmm thanks @Aldarund, is that the same as a Plugin in Nuxt or does it function at a lower level?

Comment: @BryceHowitson lower. E.g. if you want global mixin you can create nuxt plugin where u just place this mixin

Comment: can't we add the `readystatechange` event in the `layout` itself?